# How can I display a dialog box for making a choice before a CALL is processed in android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to intercept outgoing calls and pass them to a VOIP application.  I see that the Google Voice application has a feature for displaying a question before each call is actually initiated.  It provides the user with the choice:

- Initiate call via Google Voice
- Initiate call via standard call

I would like a way to do something similar with my application (so that not all calls have to be routed through it).  At the moment, I can intercept CALL events via a BroadcastReceiver, however, these are not allowed to open dialogs (thus making it possible to display the choice).

What is the best way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should listen for the intent : NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

And once you receive the intent in a BroadcaseReceiver, call your activity through it with your activity class intent which in turn displays the dialog.