# Holding the broadcast receiver scope to perform operation based on user input

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

There is a new method supported in Android from API level 11 for extending the lifetime of the broadcast receiver.

It is goAsync and new class BroadcastReceiever.PendingResult.

Our scenario is: 
When we receive the broadcast receiver for incoming call, We show a activity as dialog with accept recording/decline option. 
Based on the user input, we need to decide either to connect/disconnect the call. 
The ISSUE is that we need to ensure that broadcast receiver on receive is blocked till we get the user input and how we can pass the user input from activity dialog back to broadcast receiver.

This is similar scenario as in post which is not completely answered: [link] ([Wait for user input before placing outgoing call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401964/wait-for-user-input-before-placing-outgoing-call))
From the above post we got to know that this can be achieved using the goAsync and BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult. But we are not clear on how to implement these APIs.

Any sample code snippet would be helpful.